# Update check failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out in ehcache configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

i am newbie to hibernate.i have configured hibernate second level cache in my project like below.
**dispatcher-servelt.xml** i have added the below lines.

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">${hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
```

**i added the below jar files**

```
ehcahche-core-2.5.0
hibernate-ehcache-3.6.0.final
```

i am getting the below log after web application successfully loaded.

```
2014-12-15 11:19:01,642 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdate:63 - Update check failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

How to resolve the above exception?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: That is more than likely either a configuration problem on the ehcache side or a network configuration problem; without further information it's hard to tell

Comment: @fge i have mentioned my ehcahe configuration in question.

Comment: Not really; what port is used by the ehcache nodes? What is the network infrastructure?

Comment: i have used below link for configuring the ehcache.http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/hibernate-cache-levels-tutorial.html.can you please let me know if anything is missed out in the configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a debug-level exception from the EHCache `UpdateChecker` that fails to connect to the URL it uses to check for updates.

To get rid of the message, you can disable the update check, either

- by setting the `net.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck` system property to `true`; or
- by adding the `updateCheck="false"` attribute to the root element of your `ehcache.xml`.

Comment: i added the <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck">false</prop> in dispatcher-servlet.xml.but still i got the exception.

Comment: It should be `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: i changed false to true.but still throws the exception

Comment: Most likely, the cache libraries have already been loaded by the time your XML file is being processed, and the system property is set too late.

Comment: i create the ehcache xml and put <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true"> this lines it worked for me.